# Choose providers in ios 9 spotlight suggested news

Tags: spotlight, ios

I wonder where I can choose/ change the news sources that spotlight uses in the new iOS 9...!
I live in Switzerland and don't have the News App...

[i've never visited most of the sites before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ke86.jpg)

Comment: Could you indicate by editing the post if you have the news app itself? That seems to work to configure it in limited countries.

Answer (score -1):

I think the news section in spotlight search is linked to your iOS news app, try changing sources there to see if it has any effects. You may also want to take a look at your spotlight search settings.

Comment: Where in spotlight search settings do you influence the choice of news. All I can see is a binary switch to allow the content or disallow it entirely.

Comment: then it's linked to your news app or it changes depending your location, some have CNN news other have other sources

Comment: So there's nothing in the settings to look at?